# Does Flash make a champion untargetable for a moment?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are some effects in the game which remove a champion's sprite from the map, rendering them untargetable for a moment, such as Elise's `Rappel`.  Does the Summoner Spell `Flash` do this as well, even just for a split second?  Or is the champion always on the field and targettable *at all times*?  In other words, does `Flash` instantly place the champion at the target location such that there is no moment in time where the champion isn't on the map, or is there a moment when he doesn't exist on the map?

I ask because I was playing a game where I was getting double ulted by both Nunu and Morgana.  My `Flash` was up, but it wasn't enough to escape the range of their ultimates completely.  I am wondering whether, if I timed my `Flash` just right, if I could make myself untargettable for a split second and avoid the effects of one or both of the ultimates when they triggered (i.e., Morgana's stun activated or Nunu's ultimate blew up for tons of damage).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not make you untargetable at all, it just moves you instantaneously. The fact that plenty of abilities does not get cancelled by the target flashing is perfect proof of this.

Comment: To some degree i agree with this, for example: I have been grabbed by Blitzcrank's hook at the exact instant I flashed away. I still Flashed yet blitzcrank's grab could still be seen visually on me and I had been stunned yet I was not pulled towards Blitz. This has happened a few times to me.

Comment: The instant your using your flash you can get hit at both your place of origin and your place of destination.

Comment: @Cresh Really?  Is that confirmed?  So if there is an AoE at both locations at the moment I use Flash, both will affect me?

Comment: Its not confirmed its just my experience, you can't get hit twice by the same spell just because there is hit recognition both places.

Comment: As volibear I have flipped people right as they were flashing, and they flew all the way back from their destination over my head.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not. It just moves your character ~475 in game. However it does counter a few things;

For example, if you flash while blitz has his fist on you, you will not be pulled (Ezreal's arcane shift does this.)
If you flash after naut pulls you, it sometimes negates it. If you flash while Naut uses his ultimate as someone like yi with the ability to be very fast, it will fizzle out after 5 seconds.

It will NOT stop autoattacks though, so if you flash on 2 hp with ashe's auto coming at you, chances are you'll die.